# Disable Trac Authentication for local Usage

Tags: authentication, permissions, trac

I set up a local Trac wiki using a conda env, where I installed all dependencies, except the system packages, which I installed in the system:

```
trac-admin . initenv
```

I entered the required infos like project name there.
Then I run the Trac standalone server.

```
tracd --port 8000 .
```

inside the directory, where I set up the wiki.

Since this is supposed to be a wiki, which I use locally myself and not for any multiuser setup, I don't need any authentication functionality. How can I deactivate any authentication or need for login for Trac?

I know that I don't have permissions, because I used the quick search field for a page, which could not exist and when the wiki showed no results, it didn't offer a create page button of any kind. According to the StartPage, this means I don't have permissions.

I couldn't find any enable/disable setting for this in the `./conf/trac.ini` to do this. It would also be acceptable to find an easy way to create a user, as which I login to Trac, but all the guides from Trac documentation assume prior knowledge of some kind of configuration files and they don't explain those exactly. For example [here](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracAuthenticationIntroduction#OptionalAuthenticationForTheTracInstallation). Where does that configuration file even go and what kind of syntax does this use? Not really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you need to modify the permissions (authorization). The permissions are stored in the database rather than `trac.ini`. You need to grant permission using `trac-admin` utility. See [TracPermissions](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPermissions).

```
trac-admin $env permission add anonymous WIKI_CREATE WIKI_MODIFY WIKI_DELETE WIKI_RENAME
```

For help, execute:

```
trac-admin $env permission help
```

If you wish to setup authentication, see [TracStandalone: UsingAuthentication](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone#UsingAuthentication).

Comment: Yes, after doing this, I can create pages without any need to login. Searching for a not existent page now results in a page displaying a button for creating the missing page.